# How create a custom windows form to manage Outlook Calenar

Tags: vb.net, windows, calendar, outlook

How create a small program where I can schedule my activities and update my Microsoft Outlook Calendar (Microsoft 2003 up to now versions).

Not a plugin of outlook , looking for windows form

Answer (score 1):

You can automate Outlook from any application. See [How to automate Outlook by using Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/220595) for more information.

Also you may find the following links helpful:

- [Automating Outlook from a Visual Basic Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865816(v=office.15).aspx)
- [Starting an Outlook Automation Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb267957(v=office.12).aspx)
- [VB app automates Outlook (VBAutomateOutlook)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/VBAutomateOutlook-34ae00f2)